# to focus on the child window - selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

With the code below can identify the child window which opens after clicking a button on Father window, but can not interact with it .
I can not get the button text that is in the child window .

there are no errors on the island, just does not perform the desired action.

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();

          String firstWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); 

          String secondWinHandle;

          String winHandle=handles.iterator().next();

          if (winHandle!=firstWinHandle){

          //To retrieve the handle of second window, extracting the handle which does not match to first window handle

          secondWinHandle=winHandle; //Storing handle of second window handle

         //Switch control to new window

          driver.switchTo().window(secondWinHandle);

          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

          By tipoTecnologia2 = By.cssSelector("[name='btnClose'][value='Fechar'][type='input']");
         driver.findElement(tipoTecnologia2).click();

            driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.TAB);



          }
```

[image: Window]

Comment: your code seems to be correct! maybe there is an error in the `if` block, and the action is not performed because the `title` is not "[Ativação] - Simulador de Preços". you can check it by deleting the `if` and see what happens!

Comment: yaa.. looks like if condition is not satisfying....

Comment: if you have only 2windows.. then switch if it not parent (may be janelaPai here)..  then go for getting price if you trying to this from child..

Comment: @fabersky 
I took the IF and tried to check an element on the page , but he could not find him , it seems he does not focus on the child window and did not find elements in it.

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer 
I did not understand , can you give me a practical example , please?

Comment: @PauloSilva posted answer..please try it.. you can switch to windows based on window handle with out worrying about title

Answer (score 0):

```
  Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();

      System.out.println("no of windows" +handles.size());

      String firstWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); 

      String window1=handles.iterator().next();

      String window2=handles.iterator().next();

      if(window1.equals(firstWinHandle)){

          System.out.println("in parent windows.. switiching to child");

          driver.switchTo().window(window2);

      }else{

          driver.switchTo().window(window1);

          System.out.println("switched to second window");

      }
```

please try this and let me know are you able to switch to new window. here i am expecting only two window are there

Comment: above i just given String winHandle=handles.iterator().next(); but good to use loop as just used in question..

Comment: I did not work, I am unable to intergair with screen elements , not even a getText Selenium can finish.

Comment: @PauloSilva updated the answer..can you please try and let me know are you able to switch to new window? my bad i am not able to see screenshot..its blocked here

Comment: @paulosilva, on seeing screen shot.. I am getting doubt as it really new window.. Can you inspect on that window and see it new window or not.. In real time I encountered like this once.. Frame is displayed just like window..

Comment: does not reach the second window         b24c66ea-c66f-4cef-b01b-9ae6c68934bf  - 
no of windows1  - 
in parent windows

Comment: fine..so only one window collected.. it means not able to detect all windows.. for IE i read some where as on checking all zones in security, user said, all windows are detected.. may be you can try